# SQL SERVER COUNT LEAD Condition Group BY

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, group-by, grouping

I am trying to find a way to count based on groups and I was not able to figure out a way without having to use a Cursor. Since using a Cursor will be relatively slow I was hoping there might be a better way.

Simplified the data is structured as follows:

```
    +----+--------+-------+--------+
    | ID | NEXTID | RowNo | Status |
    +----+--------+-------+--------+
    |  1 |      2 |   1   |      1 |
    |  2 |      3 |   1   |      1 |
    |  3 |      4 |   1   |      0 |
    |  4 |        |   1   |      1 |
    |  1 |      2 |   2   |      0 |
    |  2 |      3 |   2   |      1 |
    |  3 |      4 |   2   |      1 |
    |  4 |        |   2   |      1 |
    |  1 |      2 |   3   |      1 |
    |  2 |      3 |   3   |      1 |
    |  3 |      4 |   3   |      1 |
    |  4 |        |   3   |      1 |
    +----+--------+-------+--------+
```

I now want to COUNT the Status column in groups resulting in:

```
    +-----+-------------+
    | Row | StatusCount |
    +-----+-------------+
    |   1 |           2 |
    |   1 |           1 |
    |   2 |           3 |
    |   3 |           4 |
    +-----+-------------+
```

For Testing purposes I creating the following code:

```
    SELECT
        ID,
        NEXTID,
        RowNo,
        Status,
        LEAD(ID,1,0)
            OVER (ORDER BY RowNo,ID) AS LEADER
    INTO #TestTable
    FROM 
    (
        VALUES
            (1, 2,  1,  1),
            (2, 3,  1,  1),
            (3, 4,  1,  0),
            (4, '', 1,  1),
            (1, 2,  2,  0),
            (2, 3,  2,  1),
            (3, 4,  2,  1),
            (4, '', 2,  1),
            (1, 2,  3,  1),
            (2, 3,  3,  1),
            (3, 4,  3,  1),
            (4, '',  3, 1)

    )
    AS TestTable(
        ID,
        NEXTID,
        RowNo,
        Status);
    GO

    SELECT
        RowNo,
        Count(Status) AS StatusCount
    FROM #TestTable
    WHERE
        Status = 1
    GROUP BY
        RowNo
```

This results in

```
     +-----+-------------+
     | Row | StatusCount |
     +-----+-------------+
     |   1 |           3 |
     |   2 |           3 |
     |   3 |           4 |
     +-----+-------------+
```

Not separating the first row. I do realise that I need another GROUP BY condition but I can not figure out the appropriate condition.

Thank you very much for your help. If this has already been answered I was unable to find the topic and hints will also be appreciated.

With kind regards
freubau

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can identify the groups by doing a cumulative sum of the zeros up to each number.  Then, the rest is just aggregation:

```
select rowno, count(*)
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when status = 0 then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by rowno order by id) as grp
      from #TestTable t
     ) t
where status = 1
group by rowno, grp
order by rowno, grp;
```

[Here](http://rextester.com/TTH4284) is a rex tester for it.

Comment: Thank you very much for the code snippet. I've tried it and it and it gives me the desired result. I don't understand how it works yet but I am certain I will eventually be able to when reading up on the used syntax.

Comment: @freubau . . . The the subquery and see how `grp` is calculated.

Comment: Thanks again for your help. I feel kind of stupid for not coming up with the term partition which perfectly describes what I was trying to do. Anyway I was able to replace the currently in use Cursor function which took over ten times as long.